# python-vlc no video output on macosx

Tags: python-3.x, vlc, libvlc, python-vlc

i am trying to play a video stream(or a video file) on macosx (Catalina) and sound is fine, but the video returns lots of errors. Can please anyone help? It doesn't work on both 2.7 and 3.7. On windows video and audio works fine. 
Many thanks in advance for your help!!!

```
import vlc
import time
import os
import sys

shulia = "https://play.lanet.tv/index/2005.m3u8?key=WY4SGdiM0afb6EVx"
forsage = "/Users/ibrahim/Downloads/Forsazh_Hobbs_i_Shaw_2019_BDRip-AVC_iT_by_Dalemake.mkv"
directoryWin = 
b'C:\\Users\\i.zykov\\Downloads\\PycharmProjects\\PycharmProjects\\vvllcc\\sss'
directoryMac = b"/Users/ibrahim/Downloads/sss"
Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new(forsage)
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)

player.play()
time.sleep(6)
print ('taking snapshot now....')
vlc.libvlc_video_take_snapshot(player, 0, directoryMac, 1920, 1080)
time.sleep(0.1)
print("Screen taaken to" + str(directoryMac))


[00007fdca7c60540] main audio output error: too low audio sample frequency (0)
[00007fdca7c91a30] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007fdca7c60540] main audio output error: module not functional
[00007fdca7c91a30] main decoder error: failed to create audio output
[00007fdcb7c52b80] macosx vout display error: No drawable-nsobject nor vout_window_t found, passing over.
[00007fdca081aef0] main video output error: video output creation failed
[00007fdcb7d93f10] main decoder error: failed to create video output
[h264 @ 0x7fdca004e800] get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7fdca004e800] thread_get_buffer() failed
[h264 @ 0x7fdca004e800] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7fdca004e800] no frame!
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this as I am encountering the same error. I am trying to play some videos via the terminal as I am testing some code that will go onto a Raspberry Pi.